# How to fix module is undefined error when using splitChunks option in webpack

Tags: webpack

I get an error when trying to use the [splitChunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin#defaults) option in webpack for my project. The generated main.js/index.js file throws an error saying:
`TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined`
The other generated file, vendors.js (which includes my node_modules) fails with:
`ReferenceError: exports is not defined`
It looks like the vendors.js file is not getting the same webpack boilerplate scaffolded functions that the main.js file gets which is my guess as to why this is happening.
I use [HtmlWebPackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to automatically inject all my script references into a html page and see vendor.js is injected directly as well.

I've confirmed that webpack works without using the split-chunks option. Only when using this option do I get errors.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

var srcFolder = "./wwwroot/src";
var distFolder = "./wwwroot/dist";
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development', //'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: [
    '@babel/polyfill',
    'whatwg-fetch',
    srcFolder + '/js/main.ts'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: false }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, distFolder),
    filename: '[name]_[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: ""
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    },
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      title: "Webpack Typescript Setup Template",
      template: srcFolder + "/index.html",
      favicon: srcFolder + "/assets/favicon.ico",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but maybe in a different setting. For me it only happend with the server bundle, so I could fix it by adding the `babel-loader` plugins `'dynamic-import-node', 'remove-webpack'`.